# Trying to use holo theme in Android not working

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-manifest

I've been trying to set a holo theme in Android, but I haven't been able to get it to recognize it. Any ideas?

Posted is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <activity
            android:name=".TestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It gives me the red line under `@android:style/Theme.Holo` even if I change the minSdkVersion to 11. Any ideas?

### Update:

I changed the line `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>` to `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>` and I am still getting the same error.

## Update 2:

This ended up being that my target api was specified correctly in the manifest, but not in project properties. Weird, but now as is well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are trying to use the Holo theme for API Low than Android 4.0 that's why you get the red Line you can:

1. Use the [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) project
2. Pick the necessary resources for Holo Theme you most want from the
   ICS source and create your own custom theme/styles
   https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res
3. You ca also try to make use a custom theme for Android Api 7 to 10
   and the holo theme for Api 11 and higher, see @Alex Lockwood's
   answer.

Comment: Why would you even suggest #1?! You are basically encouraging the OP to prevent 90% of Android users from using his app.

Comment: @AlexLockwood yes the first suggestion is a not recommended one. Like you said 90% of Android user will be banned to use this app

Comment: So if it's not recommended... then why'd you recommend it?

Comment: @AlexLockwood, It's a solution too, but a hacky way!! I have edited my answer

Comment: There is nothing "hacky" about it. It's just pure *wrong*. No developer should *ever* increase the `minSdkVersion` as a simple workaround, especially when the solution is so trivial. Someday a beginner might look at this answer and think to himself "hey, that guy has a lot of reputation, I'll do that!", and it'll be your fault that there will be one more crappy Android app on the market the next day. OK, maybe that was a tiny bit harsh lol... I just think its best to never suggest a last resort solution if you know it is wrong to begin with. I like your #2 solution though. :)

Comment: @AlexLockwood: you have convinced me :D, your solution must be suggestion n°1

Comment: have u used the project that i have mentioned?

Comment: Nope, I will end up using it, but this is the most basic of an app. I just need it for my Galaxy Nexus, so for now I need just for API lvl 15. I do not understand how the Holo theme is not found.

Comment: @EGHDK if you want to use it for API lvl 15 than in your manifest use minSDK=11 and targetSDK=15, don't forget to accept the answer ;)

Comment: @EGHDK i suppose your nexus run android11 or higher

Comment: Yes, but it won't even compile/run. I set min and target to 11 and 15 respectively, but I am still getting a red line. Exact error: error: Error: `No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@android:style/Theme.Holo')`

Comment: @EGHDK can you send me your sample in my inbox check my profile to see e-mail

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12932/discussion-between-eghdk-and-k-anas)

Comment: @K_Anas: The `HoloEverything` library is not there anymore. Any ideas where I can find it.

Answer (score 13):

Eclipse is giving you an error because SDK versions 7-10 won't know what `Theme.Holo` is. You need to provide separate styles for both platforms to ensure that the correct style will be found at runtime.

1. In your `res/values/styles.xml` file, create the following style:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
       <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black" />
   </resources>
   ```
2. In your `res/values-v11/styles.xml` file, create the following style:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
       <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo" />
   </resources>
   ```
3. In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, use the following line for your application's theme:

   ```
   android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The Holo theme needs to be updated in all of the style folders. Check under the values folder, values-sw600dp, values-sw720dp-land, values-v11 and values-v14.   The theme on values-v14 overrides all other themes on the higher API's.