# Error while importing android samples to eclipse.

Tags: android, sdk, themes, sample

I have imported Support4Demos project from Android SDK (from directory  extras/android/support/samples/Support4Demos/) into eclipse.

Initially I got more than 800 errors. 
After adding android-support-v4.jar library to build path still more than 100 errors exist.
Probably all of them have the same cause - R class is not generated due to error in XML file.

`error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.`

As I understood - Holo Theme is missing..

Project is imported "as is" - no modifications were made. So I expect that should work.

- Where is the Holo Theme? It is not part of Android SDK?
- Which file should I copy to which directory?
- Or should I add some reference?

Comment: Try taking out the 'parent' attribute...?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very likely that Holo theme is for Android SDK 4.x and above and you are using some older SDK in your project. You are probably importing samples from a recent API and your project is using an older one.

Solutions are (descending order of how good the solution is):

- Import samples targeted at the SDK you wish to use.

or

- Change the theme of the sample.

or

- Set up your project with a newer Android API (eg. +4.x).

You can also check this question: [Trying to use holo theme in Android not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11130313/1085483)

Comment: It is not an answer to my question.

Comment: Yes it is? If you strongly feel it is not, please state which problem it is not addressed by my answer, you pose several sub-questions in your post.

Comment: I need to know where is the Holo theme and what to do to make it visible by project. I don't want to make any changes in project.

Comment: It is not my project - it is complete project from Android SDK. In the **project settings** is `target=android-8` and in **Android manifest XML** is `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="13" />`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved... I mean.

When project is imported into eclipse project.properties file is created. My eclipse creates file with **target=8** inside. Probably it is lowest version which is installed. But I am not sure.

Holo theme is not part of Android Support Library so project should be compiled with *Project Build Target* set to platform version containing Holo Theme (3.0 or higher - API 11 or higher). It can be done via eclipse menu **Project->Properties->Android** or directly in project.properties file. eclipse automatically updates reference to the right version of android.jar platform library. Note that targetSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml has no effect (or?). I have this unchanged line in AndroidManifest.xml:

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="13" />`

I have installed platforms of version 8, 10, 13 and 16. Project cannot be compiled with API level 13 due to another compatibility problem in AndroidManifest.xml.

So I can successfully build project only with platform version 4.1 (API level 16) - in other words with **target=16** in project.properties file.

Small problem with running application - eclipse shows only Android 4.1 AVD (others are considered as incompatible and are hidden. My Samsung Galaxy Y Duos is showing also as incompatible, but application can run on it.

Comment: Yes, which is basically what I answered when I wrote "Set up your project with a newer Android API".