# Android / how to best define themes / values

Tags: android, android-theme

I am trying to figure out the best way to pick best themes for new and old Android versions, e.g. by reading this [Trying to use holo theme in Android not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130313/trying-to-use-holo-theme-in-android-not-working) where they define **Holo** in **values-11** and **Black** in **values**

Black

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black" />
</resources>
```

Holo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo" />
</resources>
```

Question 1)
Will that work no matter what minSdkVersion setting I use? I guess that Android for never versions will assume **values-11** is better match than **values**.fallback when no specific folder matches

Question 2)
Assuming above (which I think is the case), how/where do I best define my *MyTheme* extensions. Suppose I have:

```
<style name="MyTheme2" parent="MyTheme">
  <item name="android:windowTitleSize">44dip</item>
  <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/MyWindowTitleBackground</item>            
</style>               
<style name="MyWindowTitleBackground">
  <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
  <item name="android:padding">0px</item>
</style>
```

Do I have to duplicate that in both *values* *styles.xml* files? Or can I somehow place that in a shared folder? From my understand, I don't think that is possible?

I am new to Android, so I am just trying to figure out what would be the best thing to do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independent customization should be created in **values/styles**. Follow this template: (ANDROID DEFAULT)

In **values/styles**

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.

    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.

        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

In **values-v11/styles**

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```